# Can't communicate with pins of arduino mega for esp8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266

[image: This is the circuit I built]

```
  #define RX 10
  #define TX 11

  SoftwareSerial esp(RX,TX);

  void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  esp.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("HAZIR");
  yield();
  esp.println("AT");
  delay(2000);

  delay(2000);
  esp.println("AT+RST");
  delay(2000);

  }
  void loop() {

  if(esp.available()){
  Serial.write(esp.read());
  }
  if(Serial.available()){
    esp.write(Serial.read());
    }

   }
```

I connected the ESP286612-E module to arduinoMEGA, I made the above definition, but I cannot communicate with any pin except 0 and 1 pins.No matter which pin I define to serial1, only the esp8266 part is printed on the screen.

Comment: not all pins of Mega support SoftwareSerial. Mega has 4 hardware Serials. use Serial1, Serial2 or Serial3 (pins are labeled on PCB.)

Comment: I tried rx1-tx1 and rx2-tx2 and rx3-tx3 separately. but it didn't happen again.

Comment: what did you try with RX1/TX1? SoftwareSerial? use hardware Serial1, not SoftwareSerial